# Decompiled swf to fla Action script coding errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I am using JPEXS swf decompiler and when I Export swf to fla then open it
into flash player cs6 and do nothing change in fla file and I exported it to swf then it shows me very action script errors actually these are class of the fla file.

the main class of fla is so big. if there is another decompiler you have then tell me or not then tell me that how I can decompile the swf without any error and one thing is also that the swf file which I want to decompile works good nothing error there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how .swf decompilers work, you cannot get original Actionscript code, and in most cases the new .swf does not work because of different errors.
I do use decompilers to get images and audio files from .fla, and it works fine.